# Interceptors & observables : do something only when the request is done

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am using Angular 5 and I created the following interceptor :

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  console.log('Creating HTTP request');
  this.session.loading = true;
  return next
    .handle(req)
    .map(res => {
      this.session.loading = false;
      console.log('Ending HTTP request');
      return res;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      this.session.loading = false;
      console.log('Ending HTTP request');
      return Observable.throw(err);
    });
}
```

This interceptor is very simple, it's supposed to display a loading bar on my page on each HTTP request.

Nontheless, I'm facing an issue I don't have the answer to : when I make an HTTP request, the `map` is immediately called. This means that my progress bar never shows up.

I tested it with a long request that returns a 500 : **when I delete the map function, the progress bar behaves as expected**. But when I let the `map`, it doesn't work anymore.

Is there an operator for observables to say *Do it only when the request is done* ?

Comment: Why don't you remove the map and the catch, and use finally instead, which is called whenever the observable stops emitting (whether you got an error or not)? And also, what if you send a second request while the first one has not completed yet?

Comment: I can't seem to succeed importing it with `import 'rxjs/add/observable/finally';
` ... Is there a way to use it I don't know of ?

Comment: And about the second request, I don't really mind, the `loading` is a getter that uses a timeout to set a value, in the worst case the loading bar will blink

Comment: My bad, it was `import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';`, and it works great ! Thank you so much ! Could you post an answer so that I can upvote it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to do something when the observable stops emitting (either because it has successfully completed, or because it has emitted an error), you should simply use the `finally` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You should check [this guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#logging) for interceptors :

you could implement your interceptor this way :

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.session.loading = true;
    return next
      .handle(req)
      .do(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          this.session.loading = false;
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: I have no issue with interceptors, it's rather an rxJS issue I think. I don't know about this `do` operator, do you have any documentation about that ? And as @JBNizet suggested, I used finally to do the same thing. Is there a difference between both of them ? Which one is most suited for doing what I want ?

Comment: .do operator allows you to add logic without side effects. In your case, the do implements do the same thing that the finally. Just note that that the handle(req) is an observable that emits HttpEvent ( which are like steps of the request lifecycle ). So it will emit multiple time during one request. This is why you had a problem at first. The part you were missing was the "if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {"

Comment: Without this condition and just with finally, the code works well though. But in your case, should I also add `instance of HttpErrorResponse` ?

Comment: i dont think so (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEvent) because there is not "HttpErrorResponse" event type, so i think error is just a HttpResponse with an error status